# Why I cannot play overwatch in full screen mode?

Tags: overwatch

I play overwatch. It shows up windows. If I try to change it to full screen it goes back to windows.

Should I bought a different card or is there something wrong?

I can play diablo 3 and street fighter iv just fine.

Comment: I'd suggest just running it in fullscreen windowed mode.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason Blizard failed to take good care of this. Many apps will disrupt the full-screenness of the game for whatever reason. In my case if one of my computers go online in Teamviewer (hence a popup appears) the game goes windowed. Check what apps you have running and try shutting them down one by one to see what the issue exactly is.

Bonus Tip in case you might not know it - Alt + Enter = Toggle full screen.

Answer (score 1):

TeamViewer was the issue for me. Closed the program and no problem since